# How do I wipe all out all the data in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

While building a new datacenter, I accidentally have the new nodes join a current datacenter. I did a  `nodetool remove` on those nodes. What’s the best way to delete/erase any data on those new nodes so I can start from scratch? Is doing a `rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/*` enough to ensure my node in a clean state?

Comment: if you really want to start from scratch then that's all you need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to remove/decommission those nodes from current datacenter.Once it is finished successfully delete all the data files, saved_cache and commitlogs on same nodes.
When you add them into new datacenter all your data,saved_cache and commitlog dir should be empty.